# Django Error NoReverseMatch because it's missing a pk

Tags: python, django

So currently I'm on a page with a url link like this

**urls.py :**

```
path('key/<int:pk>', views.KeyDetailView.as_view(), name='roomkey-detail'),
```

**views.py :**

```
class KeyDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = RoomKey
```

this lists out a list of keys available to be borrowed for a particular room. Then when I try to head to the next page, where is a request I can make to borrow out one of the keys for that room, Here is the urls and views responsible for rendering the roomkey-request page

**urls.py :**

```
path('key/<int:pk>/request', views.KeyRequestCreate.as_view(), name='roomkey-request')
```

**views.py :**

```
class KeyRequestCreate(CreateView):
    model = KeyRequest
    fields = ['roomkey', 'requester', 'borrower', 'request_comments']
    template_name = 'catalog/roomkey_request_form.html'
```

there is a button that on that page that links to a terms and agreement page that looks like this

**roomkey_request_form.html :**

```
<a href="{% url 'key-agreement' roomkey.pk %}">terms and conditions</a>
```

**urls.py :**

```
path('key/<int:pk>/request/agreement', views.KeyAgreement, name='key-agreement'),
```

**views.py :**

```
def KeyAgreement(request):

return render(
    request,
    'catalog/roomkey_agreement.html',
)
```

however when try to click on that request button to request a key, django throws an error

```
NoReverseMatch at /catalog/key/2/request
Reverse for 'key-agreement' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) 
tried: ['catalog\\/key\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/request\\/agreement$']
```

I have a button on the terms and agreement to go back to the request page something that looks like this

```
<button href="{% url 'roomkey-request' roomkey.pk %}" >Return to request</button>
```

will this return to the request page with the correct pk? I think i'm just confused with how the url handles pk and how it get's passed on.I am thinking this had to do with something the keyagreement not being able to take in that pk from the details page, can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong or point me to some resource that can help me understand how urls pass along the pk from view to view? I am fairly new to django so thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: You need to show the URL and view responsible for rendering "roomkey_request_form.html", since that is where the error is occurring. And probably more of the template than just a single line.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the reply. I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def KeyAgreement(request, pk):  #-->pk in argument

    return render(
        request,
        'catalog/roomkey_agreement.html',
    )
```

Comment: Although this is true, it is not the cause of the error OP is seeing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `roomkey.pk` in the `roomkey_request_form.html` template, you need to add `roomkey` to the template context. You can do this in the `get_context_data` method.

Since you already have the roomkey pk from the URL, you can remove it from `fields`. Then set `roomkey` in the `form_valid` method before saving.

```
class KeyRequestCreate(CreateView):
    model = KeyRequest
    fields = ['requester', 'borrower', 'request_comments']
    template_name = 'catalog/roomkey_request_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(KeyRequestCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['roomkey'] = get_object_or_404(RoomKey, pk=pk)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.roomkey = get_object_or_404(RoomKey, pk=pk)
        return super(KeyRequestCreate, self).get_form(form)
```

If you want to use `roomkey` in the agreement view, you'll have to make some changes to it as well.

First, you need to add `pk` to the function signature since you have `<int:pk>` in its URL pattern.

Then, you need to include `roomkey` in the template context.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def key_agreement(request, pk):
    roomkey = get_object_or_404(roomkey, pk=pk)
    return render(
        request,
        'catalog/roomkey_agreement.html',
        {'roomkey': roomkey}
    )
```

Note that I've renamed the view function to `key_agreement` to match the recommended style. You'll need to update the URL pattern as well.

```
path('key/<int:pk>/request/agreement', views.KeyAgreement, name='key-agreement'),
```